# Numerical Appr Methods [When to Use]

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I've studied various numerical methods in my scientific computing class. These include:

(1) Runge-Kutta

(2) Multistep Backward Difference

(3) Multistep Adams Bashforth

(4) Multistep Adams Moulton

But although the book mentions all of them, there is scarce reference to the last one, Adams Moulton, so I'm not familiar what functions its best at approximating. When would I need to use it? Thanks!

Comment: While it does not directly answer this question, David Ketcheson's [excellent discussion of ODE algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1168879/97353) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AB and AM usually are not used because they are not A-stable. That's could be the reason.

Actually, if you use the following numerical method $y_{n+2} - 3y_{n+1}+2y_n=\frac{k}{12}(-5f(t_n,y_n) - 20f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1}) +13f(t_{n+2},y_{n+2}))$  to the test problem

$\begin{cases}
y'(t)=0 \quad t \in (0,\bar{t}] \\
y(0)=y_0
\end{cases}$

the numerical solution diverges. 
If you take $y_1=y_0 + \mathcal{O(k^2)}$ (this method is of second order), then $y_2=y_0+3ck^2, \dots ,y_n=y_0 + c(2^m-1) \frac{\bar{t}}{m}^2$ [Here $m=\frac{\bar{t}}{k}$]. Taking the limit as $k \rightarrow 0$ you get that $y_n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: "AB and AM usually are not used..." - actually... the popular [LSODA](http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/uscd1227) scheme alternates between Adams and Gear methods, depending on whether it sees the ODE is acting "stiff".

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician to be sincerous I'm still a bachelor student and didn't know that :)